# upload both images original & compressed at the time of compressed image uploading

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have code for compressing images at the the time of uploading. But it uploads both images original & compressed & also one error_log file..i don't know what it is.?? I want to upload only compressed image file..so finally how to stop uploading original image file & error_log file.

```
<?php
   $uploaded_file=time().'.'.end(explode('.',$_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']));

     move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'],$uploaded_file);

    $img = getimagesize($uploaded_file);

    if ($img['mime'] == 'image/jpeg') 
    {
        $uploadedfile= imagecreatefromjpeg($uploaded_file);
    }
    elseif ($img['mime'] == 'image/gif') 
    {
        $uploadedfile= imagecreatefromgif($uploaded_file);
    }
    elseif ($img['mime'] == 'image/png') 
    {
        $uploadedfile= imagecreatefrompng($uploaded_file);
    }
    else
    {
        die('Unsupported Image Format');
    }
    $quality=50;
    $output='compressed-'.$uploaded_file;
    imagejpeg($uploadedfile, "images/comic/".$output, $quality);
?>
```

This is my code where I compress the image and store them.

Comment: You can delete the original image once it compressed.

Comment: how?? i cannt understand show me in code

Comment: after this code imagejpeg($uploadedfile, $output, $quality); you use unlink($uploadedfile); to delete your original image

Comment: yup..it done..but how to store in specific directory??

Answer (score 0):

Use this after your code code

```
imagejpeg($uploadedfile, $output, $quality);
rename($uploadedfile, 'your folder path');// this will move your original image to separate directory
```

Comment: show me how you use rename($uploadedfile, 'your folder path');

Comment: imagejpeg($uploadedfile, $output, $quality);
    rename($uploadedfile, 'http://kwkcomic.com/webservices/images/comic/');   where  i write code of unlink?

Comment: use like this $doc = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
 imagejpeg($uploadedfile, $output, $quality); 
 rename($uploadedfile, $doc.'/webservices/images/comic/');